# Foreman install on RHEL7 missing ruby(abi) dependency

Tags: foreman, rhel7

I'm trying to use yum to install the foreman-installer package on a RHEL7 image. Ruby and rubygems are installed. Ruby is version 2.0.0p353.

The yum install fails with several rubygem packages failing:

```
Requires: ruby(abi)
```

I don't see any package called ruby(abi), and don't understand what that is. Is there a workaround?

**Edit**: Turns out there is a different repository for "el7". I blindly used the link in the documentation on this page: http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.6/index.html#3.2.1Installation

The correct command to install the el7 repository is:

```
yum install http://yum.theforeman.org/releases/1.6/el7/x86_64/foreman-release.rpm
```

This works, and installing the foreman-installer package succeeds, however the foreman-installer run fails with its puppet config trying to install ruby193 packages, which seem to have been deprecated from the repository.

Comment: Do you have the optional channel enabled?

Comment: I have the EPEL repository enabled, if that's what you mean. I'm wondering if there's an "el7" version of the Foreman repo that wasn't documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm just premature on several issues. I was working with TheForeman release candidate 1.6 without realizing it, and attempting a RHEL 7 install which is also still being baked. While I'd love to contribute to the effort, to get stuff done I dropped back to TheForeman 1.5.3 on a RHEL 6.5 machine and got a successful install.

Answer (score 1):

Before running foreman-installer you have to install ruby193 extra packages which contains all dependencies:

```
sudo yum install -y rhscl-ruby193-epel-7-x86_64-1-2
```

It's not in the manual.

Comment: How about this error message `Setting up Install Process
Skipping filters plugin, no data
No package rhscl-ruby193-epel-7-x86_64-1-2 available.
Error: Nothing to do` ?